# DOJO: Listening for dojo.xhr requests globablly

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to listen for dojo.xhrPost requests?  I have used dojo/request/notify in the past for the dojo/request API, but that doesn't detect requests made with the older dojo.xhr API.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using dojo/aspect to "listen" for function calls?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/aspect.html

Try the first example in that documentation page.